# Templated function using an unknown type

Tags: c++, templates, dll, linker

I'm trying to implement a new feature on project that I'm working on.
The project architecture is the following: There's an external plugin project that is compiled as a DLL and then another project that is an executable and uses the DLL.

What I want to implement is a generic function on the plugin that receives an argument of unknown type and is called on the executable project. For this I'm trying to use a templated function. The issue is that the type of the argument is a type that is only defined on the executable project. I think that what I'm trying to do might not be possible but I'd like to know if that's true or if there's a way to work around it.

Plugin project header file

```
namespace MyPluginNameSpace
{
   template<typename T>
   void MyFunc(T& MyArg, int OtherArg)
   {
       Body_in_header_file
   }
}
```

Executable project cpp file

```
#include "PluginHeader.h"

using MyProjectType = MyStruct<TypeA, TypeB, TypeC>

void MYProjectFunc()
{
   MyProjectType MyVar;
   MyPluginNamespace::Myfunc(MyVar, 0);
}
```

The MyStruct is actually defined in the DLL project with a variadic template

```
template<typename... TYPES>
struct MyStruct
```

And TypeA, TypeB, TypeC are defined in the DLL as well

Trying to compile something similar to this doesn't work as I get a list of linker errors since the plugin isn't aware of what MyProjectType is because although all the types are internal to the DLL, the arrangement used to create MyStruct in itself isn't.

I've tried to fix the errors by doing explicit template instantiation in the cpp file as follows but with no success.

```
template void MyPluginNamespace::Myfunc<MyProjectType>(MyProjectType&, int)
```

Is there any possible workaround to pass the type through DLL boundaries?

Comment: Where is the body of "MyFunc"? In the header file or in the cpp file? And, please, explain what do you mean in this line: using MyProjectType = templated_type

Comment: The body is in the header file. By templated type I mean it's a class type that is is defined via a variadic template. All the types that form the template are defined in the DLL but their combination is only set on the executable project. I've edited the original post trying to clarify what I meant